# How can i change the admin-secret for juju?

Tags: juju, maas

Is there a way, how can I change the admin-secret password for Juju with MAAS environment once the Juju is bootstrapped?

I know that I can specify that field BEFORE in enviroments.yaml by

`admin-secret: {}`

in maas section of yaml.file.

But i didnt do that, i have a password automaticaly created. And i would like to change it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible just yet.  I'm working on a bunch of user commands right now that I'm hoping will get into the 1.21 release.  One of which will allow you to change the password.